# Where input data gets stored initially?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

First step in Map Reduce is to copy input file(s) to HDFS.
Want to know where exactly this gets stored; On name node or data node or somewhere else ?

When we say copy to HDFS, where exactly we store input files **initially** ? 
( I know later we split and store on data nodes ).

Or its something we directly copy from chunks from source/input machine to data nodes ? ( I am sure that is not the case )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting files in HDFS is a coordination effort between the client, Name node and the Data nodes. At a very high level the client talks to the name node to identify the data nodes where the file need to be stored, the client then sends the first block to the initial data node and transfers the file, the subsequent transfer for replication of that particular block happens from that particular data node.

Read the detailed protocol [from here](http://www.aosabook.org/en/hdfs.html).

[image]